# GitHub API to add file, but cURL Argument list too long

Tags: bash, github, curl

I'm trying to use the GitHub API to add a local file to a repo. I'm using the cURL command in a Bash script to make a PUT request.

I'm using Base64 encoding for a PDF file for the content as described in the documentation, but I'm getting an error that the argument list is too long. Is there a workaround? I got it to work with a very small text file.

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-file-contents

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to pass in your JSON payload on stdin, rather than trying to embed it on the command line.

While you can build the JSON yourself, using a tool like [`jo`](https://github.com/jpmens/jo/tree/master) makes your life easier; for example, the following command, when run on my system...

```
jo content=%README.md message='This is a test' \
  committer=$(jo name="Lars" email="lars@example.com") \
  sha=bc358d0f8885825585c759af341d6293a3117fd7
```

Produces the following JSON, and handles base64-encoding the file for us:

```
{
  "content": "IyBTYW5kYm94CgpUaGlzIGlzIGEgcmVwb3NpdG9yeSBmb3IgbXVja2luZyBhYm91dCB3aXRoIEdpdGh1Yi4KVGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3QuCg==",
  "message": "This is a test",
  "committer": {
    "name": "Lars",
    "email": "lars@oddbit.com"
  },
  "sha": "bc358d0f8885825585c759af341d6293a3117fd7"
}
```

We can pipe this into `curl` like this:

```
jo ... | 
curl -L \
  -X PUT \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/larsks/sandbox/contents/README.md \
  -d @-
```

That `-d @-` at the end tells `curl` to read the payload from stdin.

Comment: Thanks, I'm providing the path to the file in the script. Could you elaborate how stdin is different and solves this issue? The base64 encoded file for "content" is too long and giving the argument list is too long error.

Comment: Trying to include the base64 encoded file inline on the command line (as an argument to curl's `-d` option) results in the command line being too long. This isn't an issue when you pass the data on stdin (because it has no impact on the length of the command line). You could also read the JSON from a file instead of stdin. If you're already doing that...update your question to show the exact command line that you're running, and we can provide better answers.